# How to combine two arrays iterating over the first row in julia?

Tags: julia

Currently I have a following- two matrices A and B. In matrix A the first row corresponds the investment type and the second row is number of scenario (1,2,3) for both investment types bonds and stocks:

```
A =["bond" "bond" "bond" "stock" "stock" "stock"; 1 2 3 1 2 3; 0.1 0.12 0.13 0.14 0.15 0.16; 0.17 0.18 0.19 0.2 0.21 0.22]
```

In matrix B I have two values for both bonds and stocks, the past values.

```
B= ["bond" "stock"; 0.31 0.32; 0.34 0.35]
```

My data consists of this similar type of data matrix with multiple investment types and >1000 scenarios. How can I merge these two matrices to create following output for the large dataset:

```
merged_matrix = ["bond" "bond" "bond" "stock" "stock" "stock";1 2 3 1 2 3; 0.31 0.31 0.31 0.32 0.32 0.32; 0.34 0.34 0.34 0.35 0.35 0.35; 0.1 0.12 0.13 0.14 0.15 0.16; 0.17 0.18 0.19 0.2 0.21 0.22]
```

I have difficulties in generating the right for-loop iteration. I am unsure how to use the investment type as an identifying key. I have tried to format these to DataFrame, but haven't found any suitable solution either. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Using array with different element types is highly discouraged. It will result in very poor performance of your code. Give the documentation of DataFrames another go, and repost your questions based on your problems wit the DataFrames.jl library.

Answer (score 2):

Per the comment here is how you can do it in DataFrames.jl
(I have given some arbitrary names to the columns - probably you can change it to something more meaningful for your case):

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> dfA = identity.(DataFrame(permutedims(A), ["type", "v1", "v2", "v3"]))
6×4 DataFrame
 Row │ type    v1     v2       v3
     │ String  Int64  Float64  Float64
─────┼─────────────────────────────────
   1 │ bond        1     0.1      0.17
   2 │ bond        2     0.12     0.18
   3 │ bond        3     0.13     0.19
   4 │ stock       1     0.14     0.2
   5 │ stock       2     0.15     0.21
   6 │ stock       3     0.16     0.22

julia> dfB = identity.(DataFrame(permutedims(B), ["type", "v4", "v5"]))
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ type    v4       v5
     │ String  Float64  Float64
─────┼──────────────────────────
   1 │ bond       0.31     0.34
   2 │ stock      0.32     0.35

julia> rightjoin(dfB, dfA, on="type")
6×6 DataFrame
 Row │ type    v4        v5        v1     v2       v3
     │ String  Float64?  Float64?  Int64  Float64  Float64
─────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ bond        0.31      0.34      1     0.1      0.17
   2 │ bond        0.31      0.34      2     0.12     0.18
   3 │ bond        0.31      0.34      3     0.13     0.19
   4 │ stock       0.32      0.35      1     0.14     0.2
   5 │ stock       0.32      0.35      2     0.15     0.21
   6 │ stock       0.32      0.35      3     0.16     0.22
```

Note that I use `identity.(...)` operation to make column types concrete (as your original data has `Any` type which is inefficient as was highlighted in the comment).

Comment: Many thanks, this seems to be an efficient solution.  After the join, how am I able to transpose the dataframe back so that row 1 would be column 1 etc. ? I found this code from another post that seemed to be what I was looking for but it didn't work: (Assuming that the joined dataframe would be dfB1): DataFrame([[names(dfB1)]; collect.(eachrow(dfB1))], [:column; Symbol.(axes(dfB1, 1))])

Comment: Actually the very code I posted in the comment above worked as expected in transposing the dataframe!